# How do I find keycloak template to modify for email verification

Tags: keycloak

I need to update a keycloak templates related to email verification, but I don't find it. the result is shown below:[keycloak template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o38yY.png)

I'm trying to update themes for this specific html page

Answer (score 0):

You should find most (if not all) message properties in the base theme. This page belongs to the login section of the theme: [messages_en.properties](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/themes/src/main/resources/theme/base/login/messages/messages_en.properties#L339)

Comment: Actually I found the needed property, but I don't find this property in any of the templates.

Comment: "This" property?

Comment: confirmExecutionOfActions=Perform the following action(s) (in messages_en.properties, which corresponds to the text displayed)